# lldb: View all registers on macOS

Tags: macos, gdb, lldb

What's the equivalent of `gdb`'s `info registers` with `lldb`?
I'm trying with something like

```
$ lldb /path/to/hello_world
(lldb) target create "/Users/kakyo/Desktop/LearnAssembly/hello_world/Debug/hello_world"
Current executable set to '/Users/kakyo/Desktop/LearnAssembly/hello_world/Debug/hello_world' (x86_64).
(lldb) register read
error: invalid process
```

Adding `sudo` or trying any other executables or .app bundles gives me the same `invalid process` error.

What's wrong here?

I checked many cheatsheets and couldn't find the right command or sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't launched or attached to a process, so there are no registers to read.

Type `run` to start your executable.